# syncing favorites from computer to iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud, windows

I can't sync my favorites from my pc to my iphone 3G through icloud, they say it will will do it through the air, yeah not happening? Please HelpI've tried everything even deleting and it goes back to the origional computer that I set it up on??

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [iCloud control panel for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) installed ? It looks like :

[image]

To use this control panel with iCloud bookmark syncing you must have at least :

- Windows Vista Service Pack 2 or Windows 7
- "Safari 5.1.1 or Internet Explorer 8 or later is required for accessing bookmarks"

You can find an [illustrated set-up guide here](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html).